# SQL Server - Service User Accounts and Licensing?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, license, active-directory

Maybe this is the wrong place to post, since its not necessarily sql server related, but here goes.

If I want to setup some service user accounts in the domain to use to run sql services like the sql server instance itself, sql agent, and others, do I need to be worried about using up user licenses for them?

I believe we are currently using CALs for active directory. I just don't know if this would apply because they aren't real users, just service accounts, but I also don't know if active directory will actually differentiate between the two.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  Questions on licensing should be referred to the vendor, and an answer obtained in writing from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically User CALs are for people, not for Service Accounts.  In the User CAL model you need a CAL for each person whether they directly access SQL Server from their account or they access SQL Server through some Service Account.

This is a CAL per each and every person that uses the SQL Server, not a CAL per simultaneous user. However, your CALs will allow you to access as many SQL Servers that use CALs as you can reach within your organization.

**Edit:** There are also Device CALs for when several people share a device at different times.  Read about CALS at:

https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx

Regarding Service Accounts on the SQL Server I cannot find my old link on the subject,  but perhaps this post will help you:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2013/11/05/administrative-amp-service-account-cals.aspx

See the sentence that says

> And for system service accounts – no CAL is required.

Therefore, since Service Accounts are not people, you can use as many service accounts as you can make use of: SQL Server, SQL Agent, Full Text, and so on.

Comment: thanks for the great response. just wondering if you have any links or sources to support that so I have something a little more official to show. I can never seem to find official license info that is very clear.

Comment: Added some more information in response to your comment.